# Simple, working example of Quartz.net

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I am looking for a working simple example of Quartz.net for Console application
(it can be any other application as long as it simple enough...).
And while I am there, is there any wrapper that could help me avoid implementing
IJobDetail, ITrigger, etc.

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html

Comment: The updated link now is: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html

Answer (score 21):

There is a guy who made the exact same observation as you, and he has published a blog post with a simple working example of a Quartz.net Console application.

> The following is a working Quartz.net example that is built against Quartz.net 2.0 (Latest). What this job does is write a text message, “Hello Job is executed” in the console every 5 sec.

Start a Visual Studio 2012 project. Select `Windows Console Application`. Name it **Quartz1** or what ever you like.

**Requirements**
Download `Quartz.NET` assembly using `NuGet`. Right click on project, select “Manage Nuget Packages”. Then search for `Quartz.NET`. Once found select and install.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;
     
namespace Quartz1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        // construct a scheduler factory
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
         
        // get a scheduler, start the schedular before triggers or anything else
        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();
         
        // create job
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SimpleJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                .Build();
         
        // create trigger
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever())
            .Build();
         
        // Schedule the job using the job and trigger 
        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
         
        }
    }
     
    /// <summary>
    /// SimpleJOb is just a class that implements IJOB interface. It implements just one method, Execute method
    /// </summary>
    public class SimpleJob : IJob
    {
        void IJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, JOb executed");
        }
    }
}
```

**Sources**

- [Original url](http://hammadk.com/quartz-net-working-example/)

Comment: Broken link unfortunately.

Comment: We are in luck, it was on archive.org!

https://web.archive.org/web/20150707071411/http://hammadk.com/quartz-net-working-example

Put it on pastie just to be sure:
http://pastie.org/10681194

Answer (score -1):

between the documentation and samples in the source code there should be enough to get you started. the only interface you must implement is `IJob` when creating custom jobs. all other interfaces are either already implemented for you, or they are not required for basic usage in quartz.net.

to build up jobs and triggers to use the JobBuilder and TriggerBuilder helper objects.