# Synchronise database A with xml retrieved data from database B (webservice) and Insert,update, delete missing column

Tags: c#, mysql, json, xml

I am using c# console application program to synchronize data. Previously i get the data from database B using web service json Restful which returns a XML document. After extraction of data from the XML, its inserted to my MSSQL database. I need to run the application everyday at a certain time to make sure the database is updated on my side. How to write a certain codes at my console app so that it sync the data from the XML (database B) and my data from my MSSQL? Insert, update and delete after comparison. If there is missing rows on my table, i update the rows and deletes if there is additional rows.

Comment: hase you tried the Quartz Cron Job?

Comment: I've already looked into it. Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows Service with Quartz (Cron Job Scheduler)

Read this question:
[Simple, working example of Quartz.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821535/simple-working-example-of-quartz-net)

Quartz is one of the best Job Scheduler out there for Windows Service